# Adding onclick=”GoTo(‘URL’) to a WordPress post

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I want to add JavaScript attribute “onclick” with “go to” function inside a “span” tag: onclick=”GoTo(‘URL’) to a post on WordPress website.

When I add this code to a post:

```
<span class="aff" onclick="GoTo('URL')" target="blank">text</span>
```

nothing happens when you click on the "text" and there is an error “Uncaught ReferenceError: GoTo is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick” at the console.

Please, help to fix the issue.

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious question and ask why don't you just use the <a> tag that's specifically meant to do this?

Comment: That's because `GoTo` is not defined. The method does not exist, so it will of course return an error... unless you have defined it somewhere, like `var GoTo = function() {...}`. And the `<span>` element does not support the `target` attribute: you are better of substituting it with an anchor element `<a>` with a `href` attribute defined.

Answer (score 3):

Add this ->

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var GoTo=function(url){
          window.location.replace(url);
       }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code for your Goto function hard to know what wrong without that?
Assume something like

```
function GoTo(url){
 window.location = url;
}
```